# How to use replace regex in Komodo?

Tags: python, regex, komodo

I am trying to create a regex to find and replace (keep empty) different names in an txt file. I use Komodo, as it is part of the examen.

Here the text sample:

```
*Cassidy: What's your name again?
Chrissie Watkins: Chrissie!
Cassidy: Where are we going?
Chrissie: Swimming!
Cassidy: Slow up, slow down! I'm not drunk! Slow down! Wait I'm coming! I'm
coming! I'm definitely 
coming! Wait, slow up! I can swim -- just can't walk or dress myself.
Chrissie: Come on in the water!
Cassidy: Take it easy. Take it easy.
Chrissie: Oh! God help me! God! Argh! God help!
Cassidy: I'm coming... I'm coming.
Chrissie: It hurts! It hurts! Oh my god! God help me! God please help!
Martin Brody: How come the sun didn't use to shine in here.
Ellen Brody: We bought the house in the fall, this is summer.
Ellen: Somebody feed the dogs, huh?
Martin: Right.
Ellen: See the kids?
Martin: They must be in the backyard.
Ellen: In Amity, you say: yahd.
```

The text must be cleaned up, meaning all names at the beginning of each line must be deleted (replaced by nothing).

If I use this: \w.¨:

Also names in texts (not the person speaking) are gone / deleted.

Is it possible to use just one regular expression for cleaning up?

Comment: Try `(?m)^\*?[A-Z][\w' -]*:\s*`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/1Ufbv0/1)

Comment: You are awesome! Don't know the meaning of your reg ex but I will try to find out!!

Comment: I have now seen the demo Wiktor - Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
(?m)^\*?[A-Z][\w' -]*:\s*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1Ufbv0/1/)

**Details**

- `(?m)` - `re.M` flag, it makes `^` match start of a line
- `^` - start of a line
- `\*?` - an optional `*` char
- `[A-Z]` - an uppercase letter
- `[\w' -]*` - 0 or more word chars, spaces, `-` or apostrophes
- `:` - a colon
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces.